# Convert to a compact form

Tags: calculus, summation, power-series

I'm trying to help someone regarding Maclaurin Series. It's been a few years since i've done formal maths, and (in fact i used python to compute the derivatives) the series is

$$ 2x-\frac{8}{3}x^3+\frac{32}{5}x^5-\frac{128}{7}x^7+\frac{512}{9}x^9+\ldots \: $$

How do i write this as a summation?

What i know:

- Every even term is zero
- The sign alternates
- The numerator is simply $2^n.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{n+1} 2^{2 n-1} x^{2 n-1}}{2 n-1}=\arctan(2x)$$